# How to change the axis background in matlab gui

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a question about Matlab Gui. I have already changed the background but I want to change the axis background.For instance, I have 8 buttons rightside, and I am using these buttons to gain some graphs. I want to change the background of axis for every click. Is it possible in matlab-gui?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The 'Color' property controls the axes background color.

```
set(h_axes,'Color','r'); %change color of h_axes to red
```

See [Axes Properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks your help but I want to change background, not changing the color

Comment: Are you wanting to display images from a file?  You can use "imread" to load the image, "image" to display.  If you want to, you can put "hold on" and overlay a plot or whatever on top of the image.